# How can I automate this repetitive design process?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, batch-processing, adobe-bridge

I need to create about 25 assets that are all very similar. The same background image is used for each asset, however, each asset has different text written across the image. See example:
[image: example asset]

They all need to be exported as PNG's and at the same size.

I've used Adobe Bridge in the past to batch edit photos, which made me think there might be a similar tool/process I could use to automate this process. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [Data Merge feature in Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html).

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The actual design of the images and text you'll have to do yourself obviously. But there is a tool called "Asset Export" in Illustrator that allows you to mass export files and outline their scale.